# Regex check if parts are the same

Tags: regex, perl

So I have for example expression, which have three parts, for example:
123.XY12345.123
How can I check if first part (123) is the same like third part (123)?
I tried something like this:

```
\[0-9]{3}[/.][a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[/.] _____ (here no idea)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only add `\1` at the end of your expression. It will match the first capture group.

```
([0-9]{3})[/.][a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[/.]\1
```

[DEMO](http://regexr.com/3b2s7)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a back reference. Back references can be used to address the contents of a previously captured pattern - in the pattern itself. `\1` addresses the contents of group `\1` and so on. But note that if you have captured less than `10` groups, `\11` would point to the contents of capturing group `1` *plus a literal `1`*

Like this:

```
$a = "123_abc_123";
if($a =~ /(\d+)_abc_\1/) {
    print "yes";
} else {
    print "no";
}

$a = "123_abc_456";
if($a =~ /(\d+)_abc_\1/) {
    print "yes";
} else {
    print "no";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this regex for your match , it will only match the whole string if third part is equal to the first part

```
^([^.]+).[^.]+.\1$
```

use this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK1oP1/2) for testing

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^(\d+)\..*\.\1$
```

`\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group.

Input:

```
123.XY12345.123
```